# On asymptotics for the number of ways to write $2n$ as the sum of two primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $g(n)$ be the number of ways to write $2n$ as the sum of two primes. Define $G(n) = g(2) + \cdot \cdot \cdot + g(n)$. Are there any conjectured or known asymptotics or bounds for $G(n)$? Especifically, is it known or conjectured that $G(n) \sim \frac{n^2}{\log(n)^2}$?

Comment: Not enough meat to justify a proper answer, so I'll just put it here. Looking at the heuristics section on the Wikipedia page for [Goldbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Heuristic_justification), $g(n)$ would be estimated to be around $\frac{n}{2\ln^2n}$, so I wouldn't be too surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unconditionally we have that 
>   $$G(N)\sim\frac{2N^2}{\log^2(2N)}.$$

To see why, let $1_{\mathcal{P}}(n)$ denote the indicator function for the odd primes. Then $$G(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \sum_{a+b=n} 1_{\mathcal{P}}(a)1_{\mathcal{P}}(b).$$ Since $1_{\mathcal{P}}(m)=0$ when $m<0$, we may extending the inner sum to obtain

$$G(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \sum_{a=1}^{2N} 1_{\mathcal{P}}(a)1_{\mathcal{P}}(n-a),$$ and then by switching the order of summation

$$G(N)=\sum_{a=1}^{2N} 1_{\mathcal{P}}(a)\sum_{n=1}^{2N} 1_{\mathcal{P}}(n-a)$$

$$=\sum_{a=1}^{2N} 1_{\mathcal{P}}(a)\sum_{n=1}^{2N-a} 1_{\mathcal{P}}(n)$$

$$=\sum_{a=1}^{2N} 1_{\mathcal{P}}(a)(\pi(2N-a)-1),$$ and by using the prime number theorem, this is asymptotic to $$\frac{2N^2}{\log^2(2N)}.$$

Comment: Can you detail the last step a little more, that is, how do you use the prime number theorem to arrive at the final asymptotic? Also, doesn't this imply that every sufficiently large number is the sum of two primes by noting $G(n) - G(n-1) \rightarrow \infty$?